# Can players always help each other to have two levels of assets guaranteed?

Tags: numenera, helping

Page 118 of *Numenera Discovery* states:

> Helping: If you use your action to help someone with a task, you ease the task. If you have an inability in a task, your help has no effect. If you use your action to help someone with a task that you are trained or specialized in, the task is eased by two steps. Help is considered an asset, and someone receiving help usually can't gain more than two assets on a single task if that help is provided by another character.

Am I understanding this correctly? Does this mean players can always help each other?

Would this mean that in every non-combat situation when players are together as a group, the players are effectively guaranteed to have two levels of assets (from either a trained character, or multiple characters helping)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be overlooking one important thing: the GM decides what counts as an asset. This is based in the narrative just as much as anything else.

Often times players will attempt actions that  can't benefit by helping.  If a PC is trying a run task to sprint somewhere, no amount of help will be an asset.

Players might also propose "helping" that isn't helpful. For example, imagine a player using an intellect task to appease nano spirits. Another player offers to help by insulting the spirits. That help is more appropriately "help" - and probably not an asset.  This is example is contrived, but its a kind of thing to watch out for.

Now, players can legitimately gain up to 2 assets for actually helping each other. Rewarding good, thoughtful teamwork is fine. In practice circumstances will often make this impossible. Many scenes give players choices that come with an opportunity cost. They don't have time to sit around helping each other on every task.